# VB.Net | Crystal Report: How to avoid Crystal report asking database login

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to produce a report, but when I load the report, the crystal report is asking me for database login.

here is my code so far:

```
            Dim crTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
            Dim crTableLogonInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
            Dim ConnInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()

            cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds1)

            ConnInfo.ServerName = ConnectionString.SERVER
            ConnInfo.DatabaseName = ConnectionString.database
            ConnInfo.UserID = ConnectionString.UserID
            ConnInfo.Password = ConnectionString.password

            For Each crTable In cryRpt.Database.Tables
                crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
                crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo)
            Next
            Report.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
            Report.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo(0).ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
            Report.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
            Report.ShowDialog()
```

Any help will be much appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after doing some thorough research. I've come up with this solution:

I replaced this

```
        For Each crTable In cryRpt.Database.Tables
            crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
            crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo)
        Next
```

To

```
cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon(ConnInfo.UserID, ConnInfo.Password, ConnInfo.ServerName, ConnInfo.DatabaseName)
```